# AlarmManager working on its own but not in JobSchedule

Tags: android, alarmmanager

The first 2 alarms handled by the AlarmManager in MainActivity is working as expected however the 2 alarms handled by the AlarmManager in JobScheduler is supposed to come into effect every 10 seconds which it doesn't seem to. I have nothing in the logcat to indicate where I should look. Any ideas of where I might be going wrong?

MainActvity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Notifications";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Integer currentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        Integer currentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Integer currentSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(currentSecond), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setAlarm("Gym", currentHour,currentMinute,currentSecond + 3,1);
        setAlarm("Swimming", currentHour,currentMinute,currentSecond + 6,2);
        scheduleJob();
    }

    public void setAlarm(String activity, Integer hour, Integer minute, Integer second, Integer requestCode) {
        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

        if (c.after(currentTime)) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("Activity", activity);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, 0);

            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            // alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
    public void scheduleJob() {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, NotificationService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setPeriodic(1000 * 10)
                .build();
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
        }
    }
}
```

JobService:

```
public class NotificationService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters parameters) {
        doBackgroundWork(parameters);
        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters parameters) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                Integer currentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                Integer currentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                Integer currentSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                setAlarm("Gym", currentHour,currentMinute,currentSecond + 3,1);
                setAlarm("Swimming", currentHour,currentMinute,currentSecond + 6,2);
                jobFinished(parameters, false);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }

    public void setAlarm(String activity, Integer hour, Integer minute, Integer second, Integer requestCode) {
        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

        if (c.after(currentTime)) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("Activity", activity);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, 0);

            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            // alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String activity = intent.getExtras().getString("Activity");

        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification(activity);
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());
    }
}
```

NotificationHelper:

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    public static final String channelID = "channelID";
    public static final String channelName = "Channel";
    private NotificationManager mManager;

    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        createChannels();
    }

    private void createChannels() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setLightColor(R.color.royalBlue);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (mManager == null) {
            mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

        return mManager;
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification(String activity) {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID)
                .setContentTitle(activity)
                .setContentText("Come on")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.notifications">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.app.notifications.AlarmReceiver" />

        <service
            android:name="com.app.notifications.NotificationService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: JobScheduler is triggered when all conditions mentioned in your JobInfo is satisfied and the system should also be free enough to handle the job.
Looks like you've added requires charging as one of the parameters of your job. Try removing that.
Also the network type condition given is unmetered. Please check if tweaking this helps your case.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks :)

Comment: Great. I'll post it as the answer, please approve it so that others looking for similar answers can also follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JobScheduler is triggered when all conditions mentioned in your JobInfo is satisfied and the system should also be free enough to handle the job.
Looks like you've added requires charging as one of the parameters of your job. Try removing that.
Also the network type condition given is unmetered. Please check if tweaking this helps your case.